# How to find the actual "Content_Type" of the NSURLRequest before downloading it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nshttpurlresponse

I want to know the **content_type** of the **NSURLRequest** before it is downloaded.

As much as I searched I found the below code as solution :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *httpRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
[httpRequest setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
[httpRequest addValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:httpRequest
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPResponse*)response;                                  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([dictionary[@"Content_Type"] description]);
}];
[task resume];
```

But i am always getting the **content_type** as **text/HTML**, even if the URL points to an image.
So it might be the **content_type** of the header which send because of **HEAD** set at `setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"`.

Please help me to find the actual **Content_Type** of the `NSURLRequest` before downloading it.

Comment: Can't you change the HTTP method to GET? why do you get with HEAD?

Comment: Did you check the result code when you checked the response? If you are not getting a 204 response, you would get a text/HTML body with some error text. Drop setting the Accept-Encoding header and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: @maty_nz am using HEAD to avoid downloading of entire content. My objective is to check the "Content_Type" so just for doing this i don't want to download the entire content.(It will increase execution time and duplication of downloading process).

Comment: @DavidC.Nelson The data(**NSData *data**) or result is empty. Also i already tried without  `[httpRequest addValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];` . but the result is same. **Text/Html**.

Comment: Did you check the value of `[httpResponse statusCode]`? Another option to try is to do a GET and request only the first byte of the file. To do that, add a `Range` header with the value `"bytes=0-1"`.

Comment: @DavidC.Nelson i will try with **Range** attribute and let you know.